# Pigeonhole Principle of 18 pennies in a square of 6x6

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I have a question regarding the Pigeonhole Principal. I essentially understand what it is but I am stuck on a problem:

18 pennies are placed on the squares of a 6x6 chess board randomly, up to one penny on each square of the 36.

a) Prove that there is a row and column of the board that contain at least 5 pennies together.

b) Show that there is an arrangement of the 18 pennies in a way such that no row-column combination would contain more than 6 pennies.

How would I go about this problem? I just can't seem to grasp the concept 100% especially one that would involve some drawings. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1) Assume that every row-column pair contained 4 pennies. Add up the number of pennies in each row-column pair across all row-column pairs. This gives $4\cdot 36$ pennies. However, we have counted each penny several times, specifically $12$ times (once for each row and once for each column). Dividing by $12$ yields $12$ pennies on the board. Therefore any arrangement with $4$ or fewer pennies in each row-column pair cannot have more than $12$ pennies, as adding one more penny on any square will break the rule.

As noted in the comments, this same argument can be used to show that $5$ pennies in each row-column pair doesn't work (you find that there are $15$ pennies), and so in fact any arrangement requires at least $6$ pennies in some row-column pair.

2) Generally, "greedy" approaches (where you build the answer iteratively by making the best choice at each step) work for problems like this. If you work row-by-row filling each row with $3$ pennies in a way that makes no column have more than $3$ pennies, pretty much every possible arrangement works. For example, both the two-blocks-of-nine approach and the shift-the-row-by-one approach work. You'll note that both of these approaches produces $6$ pennies in **every** row-column pair. I postulate that this is necessarily the case, and that $19$ pennies requires at least $7$ in some row-column pair.

Comment: You answered the difficult part!

Comment: Whoa, hold on -- your argument still works if we replace $5$ with $6$, because $5\cdot 36/11$ is also less than $18$. So there must be a row and column that contain $6$ pennies altogether.

Comment: @TonyK I don't see why that wouldn't be true. Notably in your example, every row and column adds up to $6$, so it wouldn't be surprising to me if at least one row-column pair had to contain $6$. There's a weird gap in the problem, which is what threw me when trying to construct examples.

Comment: Except.  Placing all the pennies on the black squares will have every combination having exactly 5 pennies.  We are still overcounting the squares.

Comment: Each row and column has 11 squares and each square is in 11 combos but each square is counted twice in one of the 11 combos (and each combo is counted twice in on of the 11 squares.

Comment: @fleablood where does the $11$ come from? There are $12$ row-column pairs.

Comment: Each square is in the 1 pair that contains the column and the row; the 5 pairs that contain the column but not the row; and the 5 pairs that contain the row but not the column.  11 pairs.

Comment: Oops.  With the black squares a row pair that intersects on a white square will have 6.  My mistake.  Argh.  That caused bad brain trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Rows and columns intersect in exactly one cell.  So if a row has $i$ pennies and a column has $j$ pennies, their union has either $i+j-1$ or $i+j$ pennies.

For part (a), we can choose the row and column separately: we pick a row with the most pennies ($i$ say), and a column with the most pennies ($j$ say).

Since there are 6 rows, the number of pennies is thus $\leq 6i$.  Since there are 6 columns, the number of pennies is thus $\leq 6j$.  This gives lower bounds on $i$ and $j$, and thus a lower bound on $i+j-1$.

Part (b) seems adequately resolved by [TonyK's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2177669/91818).

Comment: Interesting.  That is obviously the intended answer they had in mind. Stella Bidman shows the that some pair must actually contain 6.

Comment: @fleablood Why is it obvious to you that this is the proof they had in mind?

Comment: Because the question was to prove there is a pair with 5.  Not 6.  Your, Stella Biderman's, way seemed the most straightforward and systematic  but it shows there must be a pair with 6. A stronger result. (i was attempting to answer it your way but you posted before I could and I get sidetracked by what erroneously seemed like a counterexample...)

Answer (score 1):

As for (b), just place the pennies on the black squares.

Comment: Whelp. Right, I was trying to create ones where each row and column doesn't add up to $5$ lol